# Handling https requests without API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What ways do exist for handling http(s) requests using `AWS lambda` but without using `API Gateway` or `Amazon Kinesis` ? Is it possible at all?

Particular I want implement my own REST API but do not pay for `API Gateway` service, using only `AWS lambda`.

**I'm not asking for tutorial or library**, this is principal about `Amazon services` architecture.

This all is about `Java 8` runtime.

Comment: You don't want to pay $3.50 per million requests?

Comment: I don't know of anyway to do that without running your own EC2 instances and if you want to do that in a scalable, reliable way you would need more than a couple and that would have to end up costing a lot more than API Gateway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Invoke from the AWS Lambda API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) to call your lambda functions.

To use it via the AWS SDK for Java, check `public InvokeResult invoke(InvokeRequest invokeRequest)` from the `AWSLambdaClient` class in the package `com.amazonaws.services.lambda`.

But as Mickael wrote in the comments, I think you should pay $3.50 per million requests with `API Gateway`! :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't require the use of an SDK per se. It's just the Lambda API.

Comment: Thx, I rephrased the answer to be more precise

Comment: can you call `invoke` from a web page, specifically from a GraphQL client? ...from what I've researched, there are 200-300ms of SSL-related handshakes when using API Gateway -> Lambda.

Comment: 1 - You can use the JavaScript SDK from a web page, but you will have to find a way to use it with AWS credentials (to long to talk about it in a comment).

Comment: 2 - You mean you already have a Lambda that runs a GraphQL server? I would strongly recommend you to use API Gateway.